# Why does my flyout not use the global font I set?

Tags: fonts, win-universal-app, windows-8.1

I have a windows 8.1 universal app where I set a global font as Gotham (font family is set in my App.xaml `Application.Resources` area and font is in my assets folder). It works in most places on the page but for some reason in my flyout (on the same page), it does not work.

I don't know if it matters but the flyout is using a data template (on the page). The font weight is set inside the template and the same `FontWeight="Medium"` works elsewhere in the page. I tried changing the font size but that did not work either. There are no symbols in the text to cause it to revert to the default font.

If you require code, I will provide it. I did not initially provide any code because I do not know what code will help.

Zach

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I do not know why but for whatever reason, in order for the flyout to use the global font, I had to set the font family property within the content control.

```
<Flyout x:Name="FlyoutContainer" Closed="FlyoutContainer_Closed">
    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter" >
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
    <ContentControl x:Name="FlyoutContainerContent" FontFamily="{StaticResource GothamFontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Flyout>
```

That fixed it.

I hope this helps others.

Zach